# AWS Lex, Amazon Connect, and Lambda. Dialog flow freezes after intent is fulfilled

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I have an Amazon connect instance which uses a Lex v2 bot in the get customer input block. There is only one intent, which is triggered and reaches fulfillment fine. It is fulfilled by a lambda function and there are no errors there. It executes fully and there are not errors in the code.

I tested in the Lex v2 console and the bot works fine and returns the intent fulfilled message and the closing response. In the connect dialog flow, I get the intent fulfilled message and then nothing. No closing response and the dialog flow does not continue to the next prompt block, even when I remove the closing response. The call doesn't even hang up it just keeps the user on the line and is unresponsive. The lambda code fulfillment runs all the way through with no errors.

I suspect the issue is occurring somewhere between fulfilling the intent and sending the closing response. I don't know what could be holding up the bot at this point. I have a closing message I want to play for the user before I disconnect/terminate the call but the dialog flow is never getting to this point for reasons I cannot seem to find.

Any help is appreciated even just a point in the right direction. I have been looking through docs but haven't found anything regarding this specific issue. Thanks!

Comment: How are you invoking Amazon LEX? Are you using the SDK?

Comment: I am invoking lex in the get customer input block as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/get-customer-input.html#get-customer-input-properties